# Unable to connect to mLab database from self-hosted Parse

Tags: mongodb, migration, localhost, parse-server

**TL;DR:** I can get my parse dashboard talking to my locally-hosted Parse server and mongo db instance but cannot get the parse server to talk to the mLab-hosted database.

I am going through the Parse migration guide and have got mongo DB, parse-server-example and parse-dashboard running locally. When I use the following details in the parse `index.js` file I can successfully connect the dashboard and see the test items in the database:

```
databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: '1',
masterKey: '1',
serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse'
```

I have installed mongo db locally and when connecting to my mLab instance with the shell I can see the database content. When I use that same mLab connection string in the `databaseURI` parameter within `index.js` the dashboard can no longer see the database content and the `/test` page on the locally-hosted parse server.

The Parse Migration Guide states...

> Go to the Security & Keys section of App Settings in your Dashboard
>   and take note of the File Key and Master Key values. Pass that into
>   the ParseServer constructor in index.js. You no longer need to use a
>   client key with Parse Server.

I can find those keys but I cannot see where to put the File Key into the `index.js`.

I also do not understand why those keys are required if the locally-hosted Parse server and mLab database know nothing about them.

Comment: Your DB is protected by user name and password?

Comment: The connection string to the Mongo DB is of the form: mongodb://username:password@ds123456.mlab.com:59767/mydbname

Answer (score 0):

steps :

create your user/pwd in the mLab/mongo instance

get the db URL from mLab dashboard

connect using a command lib client to verify what parse-server will
   use.  this verifies the user/pwd you will use below...

go back to 'parse-server.js' to config it for mongo/remote

```
var databaseUri = $what-was-on-cli-client-above

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://<db.....

  ....
```

Comment: I am copying the mongodb connection string as presented in mLab. Could you confirm the format of that, please? Maybe with an example string?

Comment: mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@dsnnnnn-a0.mlab.com:nnnnn,dsnnnn-a1.mlab.com:nnnn/<dbname>?replicaSet=rs-dsnnnn   is example URI.. if long form fails then try shorter version.... 
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@dsnnnnn-a0.mlab.com:nnnnn/<dbname>

Comment: I believe I am currently using the short form. Is the long form documented?

Comment: mlab dashboard will have the long form listed in prominent position on the landing page for that database.