# What is the application id of a new database created in mLab?

Tags: localhost, parse-server, mlab

In all the tutorials I find about migrating Parse there is mention of the application ID and master key. I am trying to create a new, empty mLab database and connect to it with a new install of Parse on my local machine, but I fail every time because Parse is failing to authenticate with the mongo DB.

This tutorial describes configuring the Application ID:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/128313/parse-server-tutorial

How do I configure a local instance of Parse to connect to a new mLab database without an Application ID?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180646/unable-to-connect-to-mlab-database-from-self-hosted-parse/41193821#41193821 may help

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/ParseServer.js  scan that module and just create your own guid and use it as the appid.